# Iframes security tips and scripts

Tags: javascript, mysql, security, iframe, youtube

I am trying to launch a website for myself which people might be using in future. Currently I am allowing users to post iframes for YouTube and Google Maps etc. Copy entire 'iframe' from Google Maps or YouTube and paste it in post box just to keep it simple.

Later I am storing it in MySQL database. I am displaying this post on some page. I am little worried since though I have asked user to paste only YouTube or Maps iframes, a devil mind might put src of malicious code.

What are all the possible ways to prevent this?

Comment: Why don't you take the url for the video? It is not that hard to write the code to do the embed.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are multiple risks, some that come to mind are:

- **Cross-site scripting**. There are too many ways to achieve this if you allow the full `<iframe>` tag to be displayed as entered. This is probably the main risk, and the showstopper. It would be really hard to prevent XSS if you just write the full iframe tag (as entered by an attacker) into subsequent pages. If you *really* want to do this, you should look into HTML sanitization like [Google Caja](https://developers.google.com/caja/) or [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) or similar, but it is a can of worms that you better avoid if possible.
- **Information leak to malicious website**. This very much depends on the browser (and the exact version of such browser), but some information (like for example teh window size, etc.) does leak to the website in an iframe, even if it's from a different origin.
- **Information / control leak from malicious website**. Even worse than the previous, the embedded website would have some control over the window, for example it can redirect it (again, I think it depends on the browser though, I'm not quite sure), or can change the url hash fragment. Also if `postMessage` is used, the iframe can send messages to your application, which can be exploited if your application is not properly secured (not necessarily right now, but at any time in the future, like 5 years from now, after much development).
- **Arbitrary text injection,** possibly leading to social engineering. Say an adversary includes a frame that says something like "You are the winner of this month's super-prize! Call 1-800-ATTACKER to provide your details and get your reward!"... You get the idea. The message would look like a legitimate one from your website, when it's not.

So you'd better not allow people to enter full tags as copied from Google Maps or anywhere else. There appears to be a finite set of things you want to allow (like for example Youtube videos and Google Maps links are only two), for which you should have customized controls. The user would only enter the video id/slug (the part after ?v=...), or would paste the full link, from which you would take the id, and you would make the actual tag for your page on the server side. The same for Google Maps, if the user navigates to wherever he wants in a Maps window and pastes the url, you can make your own iframe I think, because everything is in the url in Google Maps.

So in short, you should not allow people entering tags. XSS can be mitigated by sanitizers, but other risks listed above cannot.